# "Bish" meaning swish swish bish

Tags: meaning, slang

What does 'bish' mean in Katie Perry and Nicki Minaj's song, [Swish Swish](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tvzmhjzxlaa5nwbqcur6v2d5igu?lyrics=1)?

> Swish, swish, bish
>   Another one in the basket (basket, woah, basket, woah)
>   Can't touch this
>   Another one in the casket (casket, woah, casket)

The dictionary tells me it is something like lose.
The translation to Russian associates it with bitch...

Comment: It would be useful if you could quote the relevant line[s] from the lyrics in your question. We shouldn't have to look them up ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

It is often hard to discern the meaning of song lyrics, and this one is no exception. You may be correct in giving *bish* its modern meaning of *bitch*.

However, *bish-bash-bosh* is an old idiom that implies giving someone a good thumping, and *swish* might indicate taking a swing at someone, so "swish, swish, bish" might mean taking a couple of swings at someone and then hitting them.

It may be either, but it needs someone much younger than me to provide a reliable opinion.

> **bish-bash-bosh** (exclamation)
>
> 1. North American: Representing the sound or action of delivering a series of blows.
> 2. British informal: Indicating something accomplished or completed quickly or simply.

[Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bish-bash-bosh)

Comment: ‘swish’ is a basketball term for a basket where the ball doesn’t touch the rim, it’s onomatopoeic for the sound of the ball against the net. The preceding and following lines also make basketball references, as does the video. ‘Bish’ doesn’t seem to have a b.b. ref and the whole is widely regarded as being thinly coded language for calling Taylor Swift a bitch.

Comment: @Spagirl Ah, well! There you go. At least you now know about bish-bash-bosh.

Comment: I’ll admit the US usage of it was new to me.

Comment: @Spagirl You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If no-one else has when this migraine’s gone I will. more than I can do right now